# C# Multi Thread Concept Question

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Does someone know how I would accomplish the task below? I have been playing around with the thread pool in C# and I don't feel like this would be a good fit for it.

1. Start Application
2. Check for new clients > client has items they want some work done on.
3. Parse clients request before performing task. now should be queued to be checked.
4. Check each client every (Time Interval example: 30sec) > Perform task.
5. At the same time I have to repeat steps 2-3 because i expect:

   1. New Clients
   2. Modified Clients.
   3. No Change.

Its important to note that there will be lots of clients but their task should be performed fairly fast but, I wouldn't want to create a dead lock from one clients task taking longer to process.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a "pull" model as you do, is it not possible to use "push" model instead ? That is, using events rather than checking your client states every x seconds.

If you can't do this, you can use the thread pool or perhaps a windows service.

Riana

Comment: I agree i don't like depending on the EventResetArg.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a push model where the client initiates the action would work better in the long run, that way the server only has to work when there actually is something to do instead of continuously polling all the clients.

A client can insert requests into a queue and the server processes them. That way you have control over how many request the server can process in parallel without them interfering with teachother.

The [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) is a new class introduced in .Net 4 specifically designed for this type of work. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Tasks5.aspx) is a very good article on how to use it. If you're new to .Net parallel coding you probably want to read the whole series, very good read.

GJ

Comment: How do i address the issue with having to repeat steps 2-3 and keep processing the clients tasks every xmin. I think the BlockCollection is a good idea i was looking at this last night. trying to get a simple concept down with it.

Comment: I wouldn't poll the clients, instead the client puts work onto the queue. Then the server does the work and sends the result back through a callback. What do you use for communication, WCF?

Comment: I am just doing it in .net 4.0 right now a command prompt but it will run as a service in the end.

Comment: No I meant how do the clients communicate with the server? Since they;re in different processes they need some way to talk to the server, what o you use for that? (Sockets, WCF, MPI, something else?) This determines how you can have the server callback to the cleint when the results of a request are done. Else the client should poll the server or something.

Comment: Well I'm using PDH.dll to Marshall a call for perf data so this is how i communicate with the clients.

Comment: Ok.. not sure that is what would use.. What is the work that the clients need to have done on the server exactly? I don't know PDH but it doesn't sound like a full comunication platform, although it could work just fine for your needs.